# is this codeigniter active record query safe?

Tags: codeigniter

I am using this code for admin side only for my ci site, is this db insert safe ?

```
function addCategory(){
    $data = array(
    'name'=> $_POST['name'],
    'shortdesc'=>$_POST['shortdesc'],
    'longdesc' => $_POST['longdesc'],
    'status'=>$_POST['status'],
    'parentid' => $_POST['parentid']

    );
    $this->db->insert('categories', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend tackling it this way

```
$data = array();
foreach($_POST as $key => value)
{
    if ( $this->input->post($key) )   // if a value is set
    {
        $data[$key] = $this->input->post($key, true);  //protect against xss
    }
}

$this->db->insert('catagories', $data);
```

This way if any of those static values you specified are not set, they don't get added to the data insert as `false` (what `$this->input->post()` returns if they are not set)

Answer (score 5):

Code Igniter will properly escape those values for you. That being said, you should use the input class to get your post data; not only can it automatically protect vs XSS if you've set it that way in your config file, if any of those values are unset you won't get warnings spewing out:

```
$name = $this->input->post('name');

$data = array(
    'name' => $name,
    ... etc ...
);
```

You can also put the function call directly in your array:

```
$data = array(
    'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
    ... etc ...
);
```

Or if you want to set default values when the POST value is not there:

```
// php 5.3+
$data = array(
    'name' => $this->input->post('name') ?: 'default'
);

// older
$data = array(
    'name' => $this->input->post('name') ? $this->input->post('name') : 'default'
);
```

Comment: these input methods do not automatically protect against xss

Comment: they do if you enable it in your config, which is why I wrote "if you set it that way", eg. `$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;`

Comment: hah, you might want to clarify because "if you set it that way" can mean just about anything

Comment: errr this post got out of hand. The point was "Yes, CI escapes those values for you"

Comment: no, I just wanted it to be clear that you have to set the option in the config file if you want global xss filtering.  Didn't want the OP or anyone else that uses this answer to think they're getting filtering when they by default are not.